# I need to hide the full URL extensions of my website

Tags: url-rewriting, url-masking, domain-masking

I would like to mask the `URL` extensions of my website.

If the name of my website is: `mywebsite`.
I have various content pages on my site such as:
 `contentpage1.html` or `contentpage2.html`

Normally, when a content page is opened, the browser address bar displays:

`mywebsite.com/contentpage1.html` or `mywebsite.com/contentpage1.html`

Is there a way to mask that, so no matter what pages are being viewed on my site, ONLY the root URL `mywebsite.com` and nothing more is always shown in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplier as you think. This is my case, just try this:

```
(function hideMyURL() {
    var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", re.exec(window.location.href));
})();
```

Is it this what you're looking for?

Comment: No problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's history.pushState() or history.replaceState() functions. This might help you out.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API